# PayPal client restriction by country

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, whmcs

Currently we use WHMCS PayPal payment gateway module but looking forward to develop our own module if we could solve our case.

The case is that we need to have a possibility to restrict clients to make payment from some specific country or countries. In standard payment way PayPal do not provide any payer details take a decision on our server side and not forward client to PayPal to complete the payment if it necessary.

Have anyone experience on solving this case? While after reviewing [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/directory/) do not found (or missed) the possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to comment on this, but the char[] is too long.  strcpy is always an interesting problem.

You could scrape some site like https://ip-lookup.net/ or ARIN itself by execing curl or using a HTTP library like POCO or libcurl.

There may be some library out there that performs the lookup, you'd find that with Google.  It will probably be based on IP in any event.

Comment: Yes, restriction by IP location could be an option but the proxy would be a workaround. So it would not work 100%.

Comment: @Fatalissimo yeah, you probably require an address from the customer and then refund the money when you get the APN confirmation. I'm not sure if PayPal forwards the billing address or not. There's always a way around it.

Comment: the main case is **not to get a payment at all** if the customer is from specific country. It is because of fraud cases. Also, need to make it automatic. Because of this the best solution would be to identify client's origin country before the payment. But looks like it is not possible to get client identity details from [tag:paypal]. And the only solution is to identify client by IP address. It is not perfect while proxy is an easy workaround but no other ideas for now...

Comment: @Fatalissimo -ok, you could also look at what wikipedia is doing. usually if you try to edit a site via a VPN or TOR exit node, they block it. it's probably implemented via a blacklist. you could try to contact them to see if they can explain how they do it, perhaps the list is in the public domain